# List the enrolled biometrics (and types) in Android

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Is there a method to determine, which types of biometrics the user has enrolled on the device? Use scenario: The button for biometric login should be shown with either face or fingerprint icon with the appropriate text. In this case it is sadly not enough to just determine, if the one or the other are available on the device, but to actually know, if there is an enrolled biometric.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there are no such APIs in Biometrics library to solve your requirement.

Comment: Google should really add this. In certain cases it's really bad UX not being able to inform the user beforehand what biometrics he is thrown into.